# What type of amplifier is this?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, nmos, inverting-amplifier

I have a question about the amplifier with circuit shown below:

[image]

I don't understand if this is a voltage or a transimpedance amplifier.
Can someone provide some explanation?

Comment: If you replace the MOSFET with a BJT it is a common source amplifier.

Comment: @TheForceAwakens it is a common source amplifier now. After your replacement, it will be a common emitter amplifier.

Comment: Ah yes thank you for correcting my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

A transimipedance amplifier is an amplifier that has a current as input and a voltage as output. Ideally it will have 0 input impedance.

Since this amplifier is being driven with a voltage source, it is being tested as a voltage amplifier and not a transimpedance amplfier.

Since it has a relatively high input impedance (determined by the parallel combination of R1 and R2, which should be fairly high to avoid wasting power), it would not make a very effective transimpedance amplifier if you tried to use it that way.

Answer (score 2):

It's a common-source amplifier. The input signal is AC-coupled directly to the gate. RG1 and RG2 provide a DC gate bias. MOSFETs act like voltage-controlled current sources. RD is used to convert that current into a voltage, which is then AC-coupled to the output. So the circuit as a whole is a voltage amplifier, even though the MOSFET by itself acts like a transconductance amplifier.

Comment: MOSFET are not voltage controlled current sources more like voltage controlled resistors.

Comment: @TheForceAwakens It depends on what operating region they're in. Common-source amplifiers use the MOSFET in saturation mode, where it is approximately a current source (except for channel-length modulation, which is usually modeled with a parallel resistor.

Answer (score 0):

I would "say" that parts of it are a type of transconductance amplifier because local negative feedback around the MOSFET (R1) tends to make the gate node a virtual ground **BUT**, because you also have a series input resistor (RI), it makes it an inverting voltage amplifier similar to an op-amp. Signal gain is roughly \$\dfrac{-R_1}{R_I}\$.

Comment: Andy could you please briefly explain the negative feedback mechanism and how R1 make the gate a virtual ground?

Comment: @George no need. If you type that into the search bar above you’ll find plenty of example questions and answers.

Comment: I will do that, it's just I'd never heard that be used before in a context other than an Opamp in effect having one of its inputs as virtual ground. Thank you

Comment: Negative feedback and high gain equals virtual earth.